# Logstash TCPSocketAppender dropping all logs due to ring buffer at max capacity [8192]

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

While sending logs from a sample application, all the logs are getting lost with the error:
00:06:57,103 |-WARN in net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender[tcp-logstash] - Dropped 129001 events (and counting...) due to ring buf
fer at max capacity [8192]

Increased the buffer-size to "32768" in the logback.xml file however there is no luck. Getting the same error with the new new buffere size showing at max capacity[32768]

N.B: I am able to send the same set of logs using log4j2 TcpSocketAppender without any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add a ShortenedThrowableConverter,

```
import net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender;
import net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder;
import net.logstash.logback.stacktrace.ShortenedThrowableConverter;

ShortenedThrowableConverter throwableConverter = new ShortenedThrowableConverter();
throwableConverter.setRootCauseFirst(true);
LogstashEncoder encoder = new LogstashEncoder();
encoder.setThrowableConverter(throwableConverter);
```

in xml

```
            <throwableConverter class="net.logstash.logback.stacktrace.ShortenedThrowableConverter">
                <maxDepthPerThrowable>20</maxDepthPerThrowable>
                <maxLength>1000</maxLength>
                <shortenedClassNameLength>30</shortenedClassNameLength>
                <rootCauseFirst>true</rootCauseFirst>
                <exclude>excluded1</exclude>
                <exclude>excluded2</exclude>
                <inlineHash>true</inlineHash>
            </throwableConverter>
```